# Multiply or add an interval with a constant

Tags: python, class, intervals

I have created a class for intervals with these operations below. `I` is a defined interval. How come it works when I do the operation `I+2` and `I*2`, but not the other way around (`2+I` and `2*I`)? Any ideas? (The lines don't get the right block when I copy the code in here).

```
def __add__(self,other):
    s1, f1 = self.s, self.f
    n = other
    if isinstance(other, Interval):
        s2, f2 = other.s, other.f 
        return Interval(s1 + s2, f1+f2)   

def __mul__(self, other):
    s1, f1 = self.s, self.f         
    if isinstance(other, Interval):
        s2, f2= other.s, other.f
        return Interval(min(s1*s2,s1*f2,f1*s2,f1*f2),
                        max(s1*s2,s1*f2,f1*s2,f1*f2))

def __repr__(self): 
    return "[{},{}]".format(self.a,self.b)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add implementations for `__radd__` and `__rmul__` to handle the case when the left hand operand does not implement the operation, and the operation is delegated to the operand on the right.

Additionally, you could *return* `NotImplemented` for cases where the `other` instance is not a matching instance (so they also get to try the operation with their own `__r(op)__` method); at the moment you're not even returning anything:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    ...
    if isinstance(other, Interval):
        s2, f2= other.s, other.f
        return Interval(...)
    return NotImplemented

def __rmul__(self, other):
    return self.__mul__(other)
```